# How to make unedit combobox text in smart gwt

Tags: combobox, smartgwt

In smartgwt when i focus combobox's selected value, selected value is editing. I want that selected value become uneditable. How will i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say **combobox**, you must be using `ComboBoxItem`. This is the basic difference between `ComboBoxItem` and `SelectItem`. To achieve your requirement you need to use `SelectItem` instead of `ComboBoxItem`.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. I used SelectItem instead of ComboBoxItem.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the `SelectItem` control does not provide an HTML `<label>` for its title -- in other words, the functionality is not identical to that of the `ComboBoxItem` control....

Comment: @Zeleres Can you give me some more details about your problem?

Comment: @RAS Sure!  Please read the entire thread from Isomorphic's forum (highlights include telling me to ignore my customer and telling me I don't know anything about accessibility): http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=27478  The net result from the thread is that this lack of HTML <label>'s is a bug in the smartgwt code.